# Attach Database using Management studio points to the wrong file path for the log file

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to attach a SQL server 2000 MDF and LDF which were created on a different machine and attach them to a SQL Server 2008 R2 on different machine. The SQL server files  at the original machine were located at:

```
C:\DB\SqlServerDataBase.mdf
D:\Logs\SqlServerDatabase.ldf
```

The 2008 Sql Server machine also contains the same file structure and I place the MDF and LDF files in their appropriate folders:

```
C:\DB\SqlServerDataBase.mdf

D:\Logs\SqlServerDatabase.ldf
```

When using the SQL Server Management studio Attach Database option, I point to the MDF file however the log file is automatically is  pointed to  C:\DB\SqlServerDatabase.ldf instead of D:\Logs\SqlServerDatabase.ldf and subsequently the attach fails since it can not find the log file.

Interesting thing is if I use :

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname =N'SqlServerDataBase',

@filename1=N'C:\DB\SqlServerDataBase.mdf',

@filename2=N'D:\Logs\SqlServerDatabase.ldf';
```

The database is restored and pointing to the correct paths for both MDF and LDF.

Thanks

Comment: Why management studio does not indicate the correct path using its GUI

Comment: How would management studio know the correct path? It could be anything. It's not stored as part of the mdf. It gives you a place to enter the path you want. But "why" questions are off-topic anyway, as they can usually only be definitively answered by the people responsible for creating the product. Anyone else is just offering opinions.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using the GUI (SQL Server Management Studio) and you select `Attach Database` and go pick a `.mdf` file, ***by default*** SQL Server Mgmt Studio will use the path that the database log file was originally stored on - since that's the only information it has.

But you **can** and you **must** change that to match your current setup - just type in the proper path (or select it from the path selector popup when you click on `[...]` if you prefer that)

[image]

Once you've typed in the correct paths, click `[OK]` and your database will be attached as requested.