# Attaching a database to sql server error

Tags: sql-server

This is my first time using sql server and when I try and attach a .mdf database I get an error. "An error occurred when attaching the databases. Click the hyperlink in the Message column for details." So the issue is that there is no hyperlink with a message for details for me to identify the issue? Can anyone help me? Here's a screenshot of the issue

[image]

Comment: Q: What's the actual file path?  Is it `c:\ch22\databases\books.mdf`, or is it `c:\books\2012\...\books.mdf`?  SQL Server "remembers" the original path.  If the new path is different, then you need to type in the correct path.  Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765963/attach-database-using-management-studio-points-to-the-wrong-file-path-for-the-lo

Comment: This question is not about programming. Please go to ServerFault and ask there.

Answer (score 0):

Change Mdf name in Current File Path sql management Studio won't save same mdf file name in ur system try to change it your problem will be solved

Comment: Changing the name didn't work, but I got it working by running sql management studio as administrator. Thanks for the help anyway though.